# Confusion about reference question and tags for R questions on functions accessing/assigning to parent environment variables

Tags: discussion, tags, duplicate-questions, tag-synonym-process

1. We get a constant stream of R questions on errors inside functions trying to access/assign to variables which only exist in parent scope/'environment'. Invariably the title and tags are vague or misleading, e.g. [1]. We now have more than enough questions on this topic to start closing-as-duplicates, except I can't find a good primary reference question. Suggestions? Which is the best question & answer on this topic? [2] is simpler, [3] is more complete, but its title sucks, since noone asking "Why doesn't my (assignment within a) function work?" knows to search for "R environments and function call stacks".
2. Probably adding to the confusion and mess is the lack of clarity on which tags do/do not apply to R variable scope or environment, and resulting lack of consistency in tagging. See e.g. [2] . Both [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environment) and [environment-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environment-variable) have unhelpful definitions which claim they only relate to the OS environment. Mind you, R's keyword for accessing scopes within functions is named `environment` (not scope). The potential for confusion is obvious. So, which tag(s) to use:

   - [variable-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-scope) is probably the best tag, but no one uses it!
   - [local-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-variables) or [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) might be good too
   - whichever tag we settle on, we need to standardize and enforce that tag use in R!
3. For documentation, and standardizing our terms, refer to [R intro 10.5 "Assignments within functions" ... 10.7 "Scope"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Scope)

References:

[1] Today's latest one was *"sapply can't use within a function"* which I retitled [Function which accesses/assigns to parent environment variables giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273276/function-which-accesses-assigns-to-parent-environment-variables-giving-error)

[2] [Understanding variable scopes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803269/understanding-variable-scopes-in-r/)

[3] [R environments and function call stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492226/r-environments-and-function-call-stacks/)

Comment: Note: [tag:scope] & [tag:variable-scope] are essentially the same -- they are synonyms.

Comment: Maybe you could make a query to illustrate the problem you're diagnosing. I only see 100 questions here http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=environment%20r&mode=all To the extent that there is a problem, you can lobby to add R's (unusual) usage to the [tag:environment] tag wiki... or just get in the habit of retagging everything to [tag:scope] if you're so inclined. ([tag:local-variables] seems superfluous.) If you want to take a vote on what question is canonical, you could instead just make a canonical Q&A yourself if you feel sufficiently knowledgeable.